# How do I make my textures transparent instead of white?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm creating a texture pack and the glass keeps turning white instead of clear. I'm using Microsoft Paint for it and clear and white look the same, so I'm very confused. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can't use Paint. You have to use something that can set things to transparent. (Try Paint.NET or GIMP.)

Comment: k thx that really sucks though do u know if they are free?

Comment: never mind i checked and found out that paint.net is free

Comment: @Nick both are free programs

Answer (score 2):

Technically, this is a graphical design question, but I'll give you the run down.

We learn at school that all colours are made up of three primary colours. Red, green and blue. Computers often read colour as red, green and blue (**RGB**) or red, green, blue and alpha (**RGBA**). Alpha is the quality that gives transparency.

Paint offers no way to manipulate the alpha. You can set a "background colour", and within the scope of paint, you can create the illusion of transparency, but it can not physically save an image as having transparency in it.

More advanced image editing software can generally handle transparency fairly well. **Photoshop** is the most popular one. The software can be fairly cheap, now, if you buy a dumbed down version as a CD key. **GIMP** is less user-friendly, but is just as powerful as Photoshop. And better yet, ***GIMP is free***.

Keep in mind that when you save your textures, there are certain file formats that do not support transparency. If you are unsure, save your textures as .gif or .png for animated and non-animated textures, respectively.

Comment: For future, OP, questions like this might be better directed to the Game Dev stack exchange. While your asking within the context of Minecraft, your actually just asking about making a texture. It is debatable if that would make it more general to game developing, but more importantly, you might find questions like these are answered with a lot more quality and experience.

Answer (score 1):

In short: Microsoft Paint doesn't support transparency.
As Timelord64 said, you can use GIMP to create textures with transparency. When you create a new image, make sure to go over to the layer manager (default on the right) and right click the background layer, add alpha channel. They you can select everything and hit delete. The chequered squares means that that part of the image is transparent

Answer (score 0):

Just use the pixlr editor it is free.

1. Open the texture up in https://pixlr.com/x/

2. Click on the paintbrush icon.

3. Click the eraser icon (make the size 1px for minecraft textures or the size you want)
4. Erase it and download it and now your texture will be transparent!

***DO NOT FORGET TO PUT THE TEXTURE IN YOUR RESOURCE PACK***