# Using transparency in Minecraft. How?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently, I've been working on another resource pack, for 1.8.7. I am attempting to change the *leaves_oak.png* texture.

I can re-colour fine, but the transparent pixels turn black, when I reload them into my world.

Comment: Are you on fancy graphics or fast graphics? I think transparency being black is just the way it works for fast graphics.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are asking how to use transparency in your texture. Transparency is the trait that makes those pixels appear invisible when used as a texture. If that is the case, this is a duplicate question, and you will ideally be directed towards a more suitable response. It will also be helpful if you can tell us what program you are using to edit the textures.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are asking is how to make transparent textures. To do that, you would have to edit your texture in GIMP or Photoshop. Simple programs like paint won't be enough. Transparency is rendering when the computer reads the color as alpha. RGBA stands for the colors a computer recognizes (red, green, blue, and alpha).

[Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228422/how-do-i-make-my-textures-transparent-instead-of-white)

Comment: Nice try at answering the question, but I feel some of that might seem self explanatory to you, where to the average user might seem a bit confusing. As a general rule, if your primary source for the answer is an answer to a similar question on here, instead of answering the question and adding to clutter, you should be flagging this question as a duplicate of the original question. That way, they are directed to a more accepted and quality answer.

Comment: To clarify for OP, some image editors (such as paint) save the image using pixels stored as "RGB", or red, green and blue. The primary colours. More advanced software (GIMP, PhotoShop) can utilise "RGBA", or red, green, blue and alpha. Alpha represents how transparent a pixel is. You will likely want to use some reliable, free software like GIMP to make your texture, and ensure you save the texture as a format that supports image transparency.

Answer (score -1):

Well the reason behind about why they are going black is a 'hack' aginst making a texture pack say you could change the color of Stone to transparent, then you can just see all the ores.

Comment: This is not the case, any texture can be made transparent by editing json files in the resource pack to change the rendering mode for that texture.